# Facebook FQL user table `sex` field : how to return male/female even the user is using different locale?

Tags: php, locale, facebook-fql

Situation:

my facebook application ( http://apps.facebook.com/mymagicmirror/ ) needed to detect user's gender, and then query opposite sex or male or female

FQL:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$user_id.') and sex='male'
```

Problem:
When the facebook user is using other locale, then the 'sex' field doesn't match 'male' and 'female' anymore. Instead, say in Chinese, the sex will become 男性 / 女性, and the FQL for where sex='male' will return zero results.

Any solution to query all male / female friends even if the facebook user is having locale other than english?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add one of the following functions to your `facebookapi_php5_restlib.php` file:

Function for users.getInfo:
from: http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=166745#p166745

```
public function &users_getInfo_en_US($uids, $fields) {
  return $this->call_method('facebook.users.getInfo',
    array('uids' => $uids, 'fields' => $fields, 'locale' => 'en_US'));
}
```

Then, you can call `users_getInfo_en_US($user, array('sex'));`

---

Functions for FQL:
from the link above but with pid=166866#p166866
One is for the en_US locale (from the post before it) and the other lets you pass in the locale you want to use, like so:

```
public function &fql_query_localized($query, $locale) 
{
  return $this->call_method('facebook.fql.query',
    array('query' => $query, 'locale' => $locale));
}
```

Then, just pass in the string `'en_US'` for `$locale`.

Answer (score 3):

From http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=174065 :

> Just pass english locale (en_US) to
>   the API call and it should return you
>   genders in english (male/female).

You may also find http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=166744 useful.

Comment: sorry, please correct me if I'm wrong, the link you provided only helped fixing 'get user info', but not fixing the FQL.... so matching with  "where sex='male'" still fails

Comment: I believe that if you pass the locale to the API call when making the FQL call, it'll then translate the genders to male/female which will allow your FQL to work. Have you tried it like this?

Comment: how to pass the locale to API call during the FQL call? do you mind to give me an example code? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case someone's using Facebook AS3 API: to work out this issue, pass the "locale" as param to get gender info using en_US locale:

Facebook.api("/me",getMeHandler, {locale:'en_US'});

This will return english "male"/"female" values, not localized ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&locale=en_US` to your GET or POST request being sent by your API client. For example, if you are using the PHP client library provided by Facebook (the latest version released Nov. 2), then you simply need to modify the `facebookapi_php5_restlib.php` file's `post_request` function which begins on line 3316.

Replace line 3320:

```
$url_with_get = $this->server_addr . '?' . $get_string;
```

With this:

```
$url_with_get = $this->server_addr . '?' . $get_string . '&locale=en_US';
```

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, I haven't been able to replicate this problem at all. When I query, I get the data with no problem.

Comment: There’s a typo in the example: instead of `'&local=en_US'` I imagine it should be `'&locale=en_US'`